# Correctly formatting boolean in bar chart with scenario

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop, foundry-scenarios

In a workshop I have a bar chart where one axis is a boolean property and I'm running scenarios on the backing object set that will modified this property.
I want to compare the number of true/false before and after.

However I have weird behaviour were before scenarios, the value is 0 and 1 but once scenario is run the value are Yes/No on the scenario object set and true/false on the original one.

[image: Bar chart boolean rendering before scenario]

[image: Bar chart boolean rendering after scenario]

The code of the function looks like this

```
root_object.linked_object.all().forEach(o => {
    o.some_property = new_value
    if(some_condition) {
        o.hasAlert = true
    }
}
```

The difference that I can think of is that the output of the scenario might be an array of objects and not a pure object set. But still weird that the rendering is not at all the same true/false vs Yes/No.

Any idea to enforce a specific formatting? Or at least to have the same formatting for original and scenario based data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reporting that to Palantir product. This was identified as a bug and fixed. Fix was released around April 25th 2022.